# Specify range of numbers based on the selected number

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user select a number 1000243, I want another option to range 200 numbers from that inputed number. SO it would be:

```
   //User Input Number Here
   <select id="manual"> 
       <option value="1000243">1000243</option>

   //Automatically Generate 200 Number Range
   <select id="automatic"> 
      <option value="1000243">1000244</option> 
               ...INTO...
      <option value="1000243">1000443</option>
```

OR, the user select a number of 4500123, so another option would range 200 numbers start from 4500124 to 4500323:

```
   //User Input Number Here
   <select id="manual"> 
       <option value="4500123">4500123</option>

   //Automatically Generate 200 Number Range
   <select id="automatic"> 
       <option value="4500124">4500124</option>
               ...INTO...
      <option value="4500324">4500324</option>
```

One thing is that the manual number user choose is in a dropdown option on select.

How to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: I edit my question a little

Comment: Do you need to do this in pure JavaScript or using something like jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use jQuery then you can use change event handler to update the second select

```
var $auto = $('#automatic')
$('#manual').on('change', function () {
    var value = +$(this).val();
    $auto.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        $('<option>', {
            text: i + value
        }).appendTo($auto);
    }
}).change()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a4nmkjof/)

---

Without jQuery

```
var auto = document.getElementById('automatic');
var manual = document.getElementById('manual');
manual.addEventListener('change', updateAutomatic, false);

function updateAutomatic() {
    while (auto.firstChild) {
        auto.removeChild(auto.firstChild);
    }
    var value = +manual.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i + value;
        opt.innerHTML = i + value;
        auto.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
updateAutomatic();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a4nmkjof/4/)

Comment: Well this is an option. :)

Comment: How to make that `var i` is not bigger than the last value of the `#manual` option?

Comment: @iyal in jQury or javascript?

Comment: I want to change `i < 200` into `i < $('#manual').LastOptionValue().`

Comment: I want to change that The range is not 200 but the range is the rest in the range of $('#manual').val()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear so I have made a function which you can use:

```
function genOptions (n, elem) {
    var new_select = $('<select id="automatic"></select>');

    n = +n;//Makes n an interger

    for (var i = n+1; i < n+200+1; i += 1) {
        new_select.append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
    }
    $(elem).append(new_select);
    return new_select;
}

genOptions(100, "body");
```

I ran this with the results [here](http://pastebin.com/Y5UYGW8j)

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu9axydq/)

### If `#automatic` is already defined

```
function genOptions (n) {
    var new_data = '';//Blank string

    n = +n;//Makes n an interger

    for (var i = n+1; i < n+200+1; i += 1) {//Loop from n to n+200, we must add 1 because JavaScript counting starts at 0
        new_data += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';//Add the new option to the group of options
    }

    $('#automatic').html(new_data);//Add the group of options to the select

    return new_select;//This is not really needed, you can ignore this, really
}

$('#get_run').click(function () {//When the button is clicked,...
    genOptions($('#get_start').val());//Run the function, and pass the value of the input
});
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu9axydq/1/)

#### How this works

So the first part is we create an empty string where all out new `options` will be going. Next, we will loop, through all numbers from the starting number, to the starting number plus 200. When ever we loop, we add the number to the option. When we have finished, we add the `options` to the `select`

### My answer made shorter

This is a bit more unreadable, but more compact code:

```
function genOptions(t){var n="";t=+t;for(var o=t+1;t+200+1>o;o+=1)n+='<option value="'+o+'">'+o+"</option>";return $("#automatic").html(n),new_select}
```

Comment: @iyal I would choose the question that helped you and also helped you understand how it worked. It's always good to know how code you use works

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like bellow

```
$('#manual').change(function(){
    var val = +($(this).val());
    var automaticOptionsHtml = '';
    for(var i=1;i<=200;i++){
        var value = val + i;
        automaticOptionsHtml += '<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>';
    }
    $('#automatic').html(automaticOptionsHtml)
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lcy4bft/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var manual = $("#manual");
var automatic = $("#automatic");
manual.on("change", automatic, function(e) {
  var value = Number(e.target.value) + 200;
  $(e.data).val(value).find("option").html(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="manual">
  <option>select</option>
  <option value="1000243">1000243</option>
  <option value="1000344">1000344</option>
  <option value="1000445">1000445</option>
  <option value="1000546">1000546</option>
  <option value="1000647">1000647</option>
  <option value="4500123">4500123</option>
</select>
<!-- //Automatically Generate 200 Number Range -->
<select id="automatic">
  <option value="">0</option>
  <!--          ...INTO...
      <option value="1000243">1000443</option>
-->
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/szhxff0w/1/

This is probably what you're looking for.

Use a for loop to populate the combo using the blur() event.

edit: onclick probably works better, but you get the point..

**HTML**

```
<input id="init" value = "224000" >   </input>

<select id="models">

    <option value = "224000">224000</option>    

</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).load = function () {

 populate();   

}

$('#init').blur(function () { 

    populate ();

})

 function populate () {
   var n = $('#init').val();
    $('#models').empty();


    for (var i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {

        var x = parseInt(n) + i;

    $('#models').append("<option value='" + x + "'>" + x + "</option>");




}
```