# Select ID which has not been exist in between

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

The result of the query above will be: `1,2,3,4,5`

If only `id` `1` and `id` `2` who are exist in the table, then it will loop `(1,2)` only.

It means, if the `id` is between `1 AND 5`, the `id` of `3,4,5` doesn't exist.

the `id` of `3,4,5` is what I want to select. How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you dont have those ids then what are you selecting?

Comment: Can't select an ID that doesn't exist, I think. Perhaps with a stored procedure... it might be the easiest way to use a programming language to count from 1 to 5, and then use a query to check which records exist

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, Thats it, I want to check all ID who are not exist.

Comment: @Pekka I do really need this, please. Help.

Comment: Are you using pure mySQL, or are you using it in conjuction with some other platform?

Comment: I am using PHP to pass the variable into the query.

Comment: Please refer to this question to get the idea of what I am doing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860734/specify-range-of-numbers-based-on-the-selected-number

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from 
(
   select 1 as val
   union all
   select 2
   union all
   select 3 
   union all
   select 4
   union all
   select 5
)t
left join TableName tn on t.val = tn.id
where tn.id is null
```

With `tally table`:

```
select * from (
select (3 + th*1000+h*100+t*10+u+1) x from
(select 0 th union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) A,
(select 0 h union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) B,
(select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) C,
(select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) D)
tn
left join t on tn.x = t.id
where tn.x between 3 and 10
and t.id is null
```

Notice in formula `(3 + th*1000+h*100+t*10+u+1)` and `where` clause 3 is  `srart`, 10 is `end`. Change on variables.

Here is fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f53f/2

Comment: Is there more dynamic way for this considering that the range of the id as well as its length will be unpredictable? Anyway, thanks for this answer.

Comment: Do you know the start and end of the range?

Comment: Yes, it will be passed with php `$start and $end`

Comment: Please refer to this question to get the idea of what I am doing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860734/specify-range-of-numbers-based-on-the-selected-number

Comment: It's getting complicated now. :( I am expecting a simple line. But thank you very much for this help. Thanks for helping me out with this. Can only give +1

Comment: What is the function of A,B,C,D here?

Comment: If you want simple line then add table, fill ir with sequence numbers from 1 to trillion and then do left join on this table rather then generating dinamic tally table.

Comment: what is the role of th here? it is the name of the table?

Comment: This is cross join of 10 rows 5 times, so it is generating 10000 rows, if your rage can be larger then add 6th cross join on E etc to get 100000 rows, then 1000000 rows...

Comment: `Th` is the name of column that will give you thousands in formula.

Comment: I am confused which one is the table name in the query?

Comment: `left join t`, change `t` with your table